# REGEX look ahead problems

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I need to retrieve tax amounts from html files, however it appears JavaScript does not support look ahead. here is the code and the string i need to find.

HTML Snippet

```
<td align="right" valign="top"><span style="font-family:verdana,arial; font-size:12px; color:#000000;"><b>Tax:</b></span></td>
<td align="right" valign="top"><span style="font-family:verdana,arial; font-size:12px; color:#000000;"><b>$30.10</b></span></td>
```

Regex String

```
(?<=(Tax:.*\n.*))(=?\$\d*.\d{2})
```

**I get a syntax error, invalid quantifier.**
Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: You cannot use a lookbehind in JavaScript. It is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need lookahead or lookbehind for this.  Try matching this pattern:

`Tax:[\s\S]*?(\$\d*\.\d{2})`

Then replace with `$1`

Answer (score 0):

First of all javascript doesn't support `lookbehind`. Secondly your `lookbehind` has a variable length(`.*` in that) which doesn't support by most of the regex flavors. Add finally what you wanted to do with this `(=?`? A lookahead(like `(?=)`? then the syntax was wrong, otherwise its ok.

But you can achieve this without lookbehind.

Use this one instead:

```
pattern = new RegExp(/Tax:[\s\S]*?<b>(\$\d+(\.\d+)?)<\/b>/i);
match = pattern.exec(input);
alert(match[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for a lookahead is `(?=`, not `(=?`.

That aside, you don't want a lookahead, or a lookbehind (which JS doesn't support). You just want to match:

```
Tax:.*\n.*(\$\d*.\d{2})
```